# Botão cinza em uma versão antiga do Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou fazendo um aplicativo, onde os botão são verdes,e ficam verdes quando testo no Android 6.0, mas quando testo o Android KiKat o botão fica cinza.

Comment: cara, poste o seu XML e qualquer código que possa nos ajudar a resolver o problema. Obrigado

Comment: Posta o layout do seus themas e do botão

Answer (score -1):

Melhor você postar o XML com os botões.

Mas se você está setando as imagens dele através de um src:

```
android:src="@drawable/imagem"
```

Então sete o background para null:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Vai resolver o problema.

Abraços.